# How to show $Hom(V,V)\rightarrow Hom(V_x,V_x)$ is injective, V being semi-stable

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles

Let $V$ be a semi-stable vector bundle over a smooth irreducible projective curve of genus $g\geq 2$.

Let $x\in X$. How do we show that the canonical map $Hom(V,V)\rightarrow Hom(V_x,V_x)$  which sends $f$ to $f_x$ (i.e., $f$ restricted to the fiber $V_x$) is injective.

Comment: Under these hypotheses isn't the RHS just $\mathscr{H}om(V,V)_x$? So you have some stalk map for a locally free sheaf $\mathscr{H}om(V,V)$ with no associated points. I'm not sure the other hypotheses are really needed.

Comment: The $Hom(V,V)$ is not sheaf hom.

Comment: I understand that. For every sheaf $F$ and open set $U \ni P$ I have maps $F(U)\to F_P$. The global sections of sheaf Hom are your Hom, do you agree?

Comment: @Hoot Yes, I agree. But those maps are not injective  maps in general.

Comment: I agree in turn! But this is a locally free sheaf on an integral scheme. I don't see how a section could be supported on a proper closed subset. Maybe I've gone nuts.

Comment: @Hoot We need to show if $f,g\in Hom(V,V)$ and  $f_x=g_x$ (for a particular) $x\in X$ then $f=g$.

Comment: I am trying to abstract this all away into a general fact: if I have a coherent sheaf $F$ on a noetherian scheme $X$ then the map $F(X) \to \bigcup_{P \in \operatorname{Ass} F} F_P$ is injective. Here I think the only associated prime is the generic point, let's call it $\xi$. Then the composite $F(X) \to F_x \to F_\xi$ is injective, so the first map is injective (in fact the second is as well). Still nuts?

Comment: @Hoot $F(X) \to \bigcup_{P \in \operatorname{Ass} F} F_P$ is injective doesn't imply $F(X)\rightarrow F_x$ is injective!

Comment: In your case there is only one associated point, the generic point, because the sheaf $F$ is locally free on something integral. Do you agree with this?

Comment: Look at the second page first line-http://ac.els-cdn.com/0021869389900549/1-s2.0-0021869389900549-main.pdf?_tid=69a81730-3421-11e6-a3fb-00000aacb35f&acdnat=1466123059_1bf1b1e93bdbbf0fb8a56c2aec4b8a6c

Comment: Okay, I see a problem: I'm thinking of $V$ as a locally free sheaf. When you say $V_x$ you mean the _fiber_ (and you used that word, that's totally my fault, sorry) $V \otimes k(x)$. I think it would have been helpful to include this remark about the rank in the question. Do you need this irreducibility hypothesis too? I'll think about this. Interesting question!